# IIS Metabase C++ examples

Tags: c++, windows, iis, metabase

Could anybody point be in the direction of some examples with creating/editing/removing IIS Web/FTP sites and their respective virtual directories. As MSDN doesn't seem to give many C++ based examples.

Thanks

Comment: For what version of IIS? The relevant APIs are completely different for IIS 5 vs. 6 vs. 7...

Comment: Currently focusing on IIS 6.0 but I need to do IIS 7.0 too.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524505(VS.90).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398762(VS.90).aspx)?

Comment: @ildjarn yes I have, I have already got some methods working. However, I am looking for code based examples to speed up my understanding. As a lot of the examples seem to be in VBS

Comment: And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524767(VS.90).aspx)? IIS 6's management API is WMI-based; it seems to me you just need to read up on WMI, not IIS specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The VCDeploy tool from the ATL Server source code is one example I know of: http://atlserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3691#.

This is the command line tool that implements the Web Deployment build step in Visual C++ 2005.